# Website architecture using auth0, AWS and server

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-services

Building my first full stack website. I have an architecture doubt.

What I have:

- golang backend
- react frontend
- auth0 authentication
- aws amplify

I am considering to create [this architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NahD.png), I think that I am misleading with something. The front-end connect direct with s3 bucket to put private images there, but I am not sure if I should do it direct or send the request to my server and then the server update the s3. Searching for solutions, it seams that amplify is great for serverless, but in my application should I change amplify for cloudfront?

Answer (score 1):

You can upload directly from frontend. But  make sure you are **sanitizing the files you upload**. The downside is you will have to **add you AWS S3 access credentials in frontend**.

If you do it through your server, which **I assume to be an AWS service you can give access to S3 for that service through IAM and no credentials required to be stored**. And the downside here is an **additional hop and latency while uploading big files**.

It's a choice for you to make based on your requirements now.